# Spring Boot Test not working with Java 11

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, querydsl, java-11, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to upgrade my existing Java 8 multi-project gradle application to Java 11. After fixing a few compilation issues, I ended up getting issues in test cases. When i run a test in Intellij, it throws the following error:

**Error:java: Attempt to recreate a file for type {QueryDsl classes}**

It is trying to generate the Querydsl classes but since those classes are already there, the test is throwing exception.

I'm using Java11, IntelliJ 2019, Gradle 5 to run the application.

These tests are working as expected in Java8.

I've no idea what is causing this error. Can anybody please help me in understanding this.

Code snippets are given below.

Root project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
     mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE)
    classpath("net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.21")
  }
}
subprojects {

  apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

  task allDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}

  jar {
    baseName = "${parent.name}-${project.name}"
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      java {
        srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'build/generated/sources/main/java', 'build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sub-project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'

bootJar {
  baseName = "test"
  version =  "1.0.0"
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 2.1.4.RELEASE")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.1.3")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.1.3")
    annotationProcessor(
          "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.3:jpa",
          "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"
  )
  annotationProcessor("org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final")

  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.4.RELEASE")
  testCompile("com.h2database:h2:2.1.4.RELEASE")
}
```

Integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainClass.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ServiceImplTest {

  @Autowired
  private Service1Impl service;

  @Test
  public void getData() {
    Data data = service.getData();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, data.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Codo I've added the necessary code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was with the order of the dependencies in gradle. Somehow the java compiler in intellij can not work well.

Be sure you have this dependencies for QueryDSL

```
annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: querydsl_version, classifier: 'jpa'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: hibernate_jpa_version
    annotationProcessor group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: javax_annotation_version
```

Delete the out folder in your project just in case and rebuild with Ctrl+f9.

Note aside, executing build from gradle and test command worked fine. Check this out https://blog.jdriven.com/2018/10/using-querydsl-annotation-processor-with-gradle-and-intellij-idea/

Comment: I changed the order of the dependencies and kept it same as mentioned in the link. Deleted out folder and rebuilt, still getting the same error while running tests in intellij